# How to use the value found in file for further calculations

Tags: python, string, variables, integer, g-code

I have wrriten this code with the great help from two stackoverflow users. It is the code that is supposed to extract value of filament used from the GCODE (a code for 3D printer to create objects). So far it is working good and the value is shown in the tkinter window as I want. The thing is that this value is expressing Volume of the filament used. Now I would like to two two other values to be calculated and displayed in tkinter window as well 1)mass which will be the `volume*1,13` and then price which will be newly found `mass*0.175`. The problem is that I can't figure out how to use this value which is found in the gcode and make it usable for calculations. `self.value` is the initial variable that is found from the loaded file (here I attach the sample gcode file that you can use to test the code: [smaple gcode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jadu94v9fji4fhb/holder.gcode?dl=0)). I think the problem is that this value is a String and it should be an integer to make calculation int he code I have tried to change it to integer but it didn't work so I have commented it out. Thank you very much for all possible tips and help.

P.S Additionaly I would like the status bar to change after I upload the file, I have also problems achieving this.

The wholde code:

```
from tkinter import *
import re
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

# Here, we are creating our class, Window, and inheriting from the Frame
# class. Frame is a class from the tkinter module. (see Lib/tkinter/__init__)
class Window(Frame):

    # Define settings upon initialization. Here you can specify
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        # parameters that you want to send through the Frame class. 
        Frame.__init__(self, master)   

        #reference to the master widget, which is the tk window                 
        self.master = master

        #with that, we want to then run init_window, which doesn't yet exist
        self.init_window()

    # Load the gcode file in and extract the filament value
    def get_filament_value(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, 'r') as f_gcode:
            data = f_gcode.read()
            re_value = re.search('filament used = .*? \(([0-9.]+)', data)

            if re_value:
                value = float(re_value.group(1))
                return('Volume of the print is {} cm3'.format(value))
            else:
                value = 0.0
                return('Filament volume was not found in {}'.format(fileName))
        return value

    def read_gcode(self):
        root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("GCODE files", "*.gcode"), ("All files", "*.*")))
#       self.value.set(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))

        volume = self.get_filament_value(root.fileName)
        mass = volume * 1.13
        price = mass * 0.175

        self.volume_text.set('Volume is {}'.format(volume))
        self.mass_text.set('Mass is {}'.format(mass))
        self.price_text.set('Price is {}'.format(price))

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def about_popup(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("About", "Small software created by Bartosz Domagalski to find used filament parameters from Sli3er generated GCODE")

    #Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):

        # changing the title of our master widget      
        self.master.title("Filament Data")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # creating a menu instance
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # create the file object)
        file = Menu(menu)
        help = Menu(menu)

        # adds a command to the menu option, calling it exit, and the
        # command it runs on event is client_exit
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        help.add_command(label="About", command=self.about_popup)

        #added "file" to our menu
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)


        #Creating the labels
        l_instruction = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=TOP, text="Load GCODE file to find volume, \n weight and price of used filament.")
        l_instruction.pack()


        #Creating the button
        gcodeButton = Button(self, text="Load GCODE", command=self.read_gcode)
        gcodeButton.pack()
#        gcodeButton.place(x=60, y=50)

        #Label of the used filament

        l1 = Label(self, text="")
        l1.pack()
        l2 = Label(self, text="")
        l2.pack()

        self.volume_text = StringVar()
        l = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.volume_text)
        l.pack()

        self.mass_text = StringVar()
        m = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.mass_text)
        m.pack()

        self.price_text = StringVar()
        p = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.price_text)
        p.pack()


        #status Bar
        status = Label(self, text="Waiting for file...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

# root window created. Here, that would be the only window, but you can later have windows within windows.
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False,height=False);
root.geometry("220x300")


#creation of an instance
app = Window(root)

#mainloop 
root.mainloop()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/domagalski/Desktop/test.py", line 112, in <module>
    app = Window(root)
  File "/Users/domagalski/Desktop/test.py", line 20, in init
    self.init_window()
  File "/Users/domagalski/Desktop/test.py", line 95, in init_window
    self.mass = self.value(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.‌​py", line 1939, in getattr
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'fileName'
```

Comment: `int(self.mass)` → int returns a new integer, it does not magically changes `self.mass` from a string to an integer. You should store the result somewhere

Comment: Ok, what would be then a proper conversion?

Comment: try with `self.mass = int(self.mass)` or (as proposed by Nils) `self.mass = float(self.mass)`

Comment: `self.mass = self.value.set(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))
        self.nass = float(self.mass)
        m = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.mass)
        m.pack()` When I type this I still get and error while compiling.

Comment: I think that this bit is wrong self.mass = self.value(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))  the one that correlates new value form to the old, existing one but I am clueless how to fix it.

Comment: However, the problem is clear: you are accessing `root.fileName` before setting it.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I didn't state this but I think it's obvious, I am a total newbie if it comes to python and programming in general. That is why I am reaching out. I am also trying to make something small but handy for the 3D Printers. Could you please elaborate on your previous comment and possibly help me out to solve the problem? If I don't access this root.fileName first, won't I be able to extract this value from the gcode file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `init_window` method, you are trying to access `root.fileName`:

```
def init_window(self):
    # ...
    self.mass = self.value.set(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))
    # ...
```

`root.fileName` gets set in `read_gcode`:

```
def read_gcode(self):
    root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("GCODE files", "*.gcode"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    # ...
```

But `read_gcode` gets called only when the user clicks a button:

```
gcodeButton = Button(self, text="Load GCODE", command=self.read_gcode)
```

Because you need the user to click the *Load GCODE* button in order to obtain the file name, you should remove the `self.mass = ...` code from `init_window`: when `init_window` gets called, `root.fileName` is not available yet. Move that code inside `read_gcode`.

Another problem you have is that you are assigning `self.mass` to the value returned by `self.value.set()`, which is `None`. You should instead use the return value from `self.get_filament_value()`.

In other words, change this:

```
def get_filament_value(self, fileName):
    # ...
        if re_value:
            value = float(re_value.group(1))
            return('Volume of the print is {} cm3'.format(value))
        else:
            value = 0.0
            return('Filament volume was not found in {}'.format(fileName))
    return value

def read_gcode(self):
    root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("GCODE files", "*.gcode"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    self.value.set(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))

def init_window(self):
    # ...

    self.value = StringVar()
    l = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.value)
    l.pack()

    # self.mass = self.value.set(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))
    # int(self.mass)
    # m = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.mass)
    # m.pack()

    # ...
```

to this:

```
def get_filament_value(self, fileName):
    # ...
        if re_value:
            return float(re_value.group(1))
        else:
            return 0.0

def read_gcode(self):
    root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("GCODE files", "*.gcode"), ("All files", "*.*")))

    volume = self.get_filament_value(root.fileName)
    mass = volume * 1.13

    self.volume_text.set('Volume is {}'.format(volume))
    self.mass_text.set('Mass is {}'.format(mass))

def init_window(self):
    # ...
    self.volume_text = StringVar()
    self.mass_text = StringVar()

    volume_label = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.volume_text)
    volume_label.pack()

    mass_label = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.mass_text)
    mass_label.pack()
    # ...
```

Comment: Ok, so I have placed it as you suggested and when I compile it is ok, but when I try to upload file I get following error: 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/domagalski/Desktop/test.py", line 41, in read_gcode
    self.nass = float(self.mass)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Ok, I am now not getting any errors at all but the value of self.mass is not displayed in the tkinter window. I tried also to move the `Label` command to the `def init_window` where the rest of Labels are but also nothing is displayed.

Comment: Also this self.mass has to be equal to self.value*1.13 now I have tried to add this multiplication factor and I get errors no matter how I do it.

Comment: Unfortunately there still is an error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/domagalski/Desktop/test.py", line 40, in read_gcode
    self.mass = float(self.get_filament_value(root.fileName))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Volume of the print is 19.1 cm3'

Comment: More over I am unsure why there self.mass is now changed into self.value as I think that the self.value is the initial data taken out of the gcode.

Comment: @Bart: I'm have no experience with tkinter, but examples show that you should pass a `StringVar` object to labels. The error you get is caused by the fact that your `get_filament_value` returns a string instead of a number. Remove `return 'Volume of the point...'` and just use `return value`. Also: `get_filament_value` returns a volume, but you want the mass. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: I thought I have explained that well enough in initial post. But to rephrase it: The gcode file is a many many lines instruction for the printer what to do and how to move in one of this lines is stored value of volume of filament used, this value is stored as volume and expressed in cm3. What i want the program to do is to have a button to load any gcode file, then this value of Volume in cm3 has to be found in the file, once the value is found I would like to have it shown in the tkinter and then use it to calculate 2 more values mass=volume*1.13 and price=mass*0.175.

Comment: I am using the StringVar to pass it to the labels. That it what I have now in the init_window: self.mass = StringVar()
        m = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.mass)
        m.pack()
I realised that this is a problem of having a string instead of the number, but the question is how to change it.

Comment: @Bart: do not use `textvariable=self.mass`. Use `textvariable=self.value`. Then, to chance the value, use `self.value.set`.

Comment: But in this way there will be two self values? Or am I misunderstanding something here. Because that is how I am displaying the first value (of volume) in the Label - you can see in the initial code I posted in question. Now I edited also the main code so you can see how exactly I have it.

Comment: In the initial code I see a lot of confusion :D Let me try again and let's see if the new code does what you want

Comment: I can imagine that code looks bad this is my first python code so I guess that is why. ;) I just updated it so now it is the newest version I have.

Comment: It looks better and better ;)  I updated again a main code with what I have made now but when I load gcode I get this: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/domagalski/Desktop/test.py", line 41, in read_gcode
    mass = volume * 1.13
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: @Bart: you have not changed your `get_filament_value`. It is still returning a string.

Comment: YES ! Now it is working like a charm, thank you so much for the patience and time!!! Btw, is there a way to approximate the number to the second digit after coma?

Comment: Also if I could exploit you more it would be great to make the status bar to update after the file was uploaded with the message " File <here the filename> is uploaded "

Comment: For the status bar: I can't help you, I have no experience with tkinter. For rounding: use `{:.2f}` instead of `{}` in your format string

Comment: Ok, perfect that worked too! I understand anyhow you helped me a lot :) Thanks!